# ServiceStack - How to set up C# Server Events Client?

Tags: client, servicestack

I'm trying to use C# Server Events Client and the rest provided clients for demonstration purpose. But I'm not quite sure how to set them up? Is this C# Server Events Client a c# console client or web application? I assume I would need to create a new project and put client code in? I couldn't find any tutorial related to this.

What I have done so far:

```
using ServiceStack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SimByte.RV.VPS.ConsoleClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServerEventConnect connectMsg = null;
            var msgs = new List<ServerEventMessage>();
            var commands = new List<ServerEventMessage>();
            var errors = new List<Exception>();

            var client = new ServerEventsClient(
    "http://localhost:58158/api/event-stream", channels: "OfficialPricesPush")
            {
                OnConnect = e => connectMsg = e,
                OnCommand = commands.Add,
                OnMessage = msgs.Add,
                OnException = errors.Add,
            }.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, doesn't give me what I need. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The [ServerEventsClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServerEventsClient.cs) is just a normal C# class that listens to a Server Event Stream in a background thread. You can use it in any C# Application, e.g. Console/Winforms/Wpf Apps, ASP.NET Web Application, Windows Services, Xamarin C# Android App, etc.

If this is meant to be a long running Console Application that processes Server Events you need to prevent the Application from finishing and terminating the Application which you can prevent by putting the main thread to sleep on the last line with:

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

Also check out [ServerEventTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/ServerEventTests.cs) for NUnit examples on how to configure and handle message from Server Events.